# How to write a variable within SQL using Dateadd and DateDiff for finding the last TWO days of the previous month

Tags: sql, sql-server, datediff, dateadd

I am trying to write a variable using the dateadd and datediff that shows the last two days of previous month. One variable will be the second to last day of the previous month, the one I am having trouble with. The other will be the last day of the previous month, the one I was able to get. I am using SQL Server.

I've tried looking for it on Stack and I have only seen the last day of the previous month given and NOT the second to last day. I tried learning the dateadd and datediff, (which I still want to do).

This is what I tried so far:

```
Declare @CurrentMonth as date = '3/1/2019'
Declare @SecLastDayPrevMonth as date = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @currentmonth), -2) 
Declare @LastDayPrevMonth as date = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @currentmonth), -1)
```

The results I am getting for the seclastdayPrevMonth is 2/28/2019. Instead I would want 2/27/2019

I am also getting 2/28/2019 for lastdayprevmonth which is what I want.

I am writing variables because the current month will change every month, and instead of having to update the other days I need within my query, I want to use variables so I am only updating the current month and everything else is flowing through.

And explanation as to why my dateadd/datediff is wrong and an explanation for why the correct dateadd/datediff is the way it is, will be very helpful

Comment: what is @recmonth?

Comment: whoops, I am sorry, when you see recmonth, that was suppose to be currentmonth, I can change that now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not refer to the last day when calculating the second last day? Also, your usage of `DATEADD` is very weird. The syntax is `DATEADD(interval, increment, datetime)`

```
Declare @recmonth as date = '3/1/2019'
Declare @LastDayPrevMonth as date = EOMONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, -1, @RecMonth))
Declare @SecLastDayPrevMonth as date = DATEADD(DAY, -1, @LastDayPrevMonth)


SELECT @SecLastDayPrevMonth, @LastDayPrevMonth
```

So we can calculate the last day of the previous month by subtracting one month from a date and then calling `EOMONTH`, which returns the last day of a given month. Then the second last day is just subtracting one day from that.

Yields:

```
SecLastDayPrevMonth LastDayPrevMonth
------------------- ----------------
2019-02-27          2019-02-28
```

Comment: wow, I completely forgot about the EOMONTH function. I used this in my other variable a while back and just blanked. I thought my dateadd looked very wonky, but I got this from a website and it seemed to work so I just went with it. However, when trying to learn dateadd didn't look right, but because it worked for one of them I assumed it was me who wasn't reading it correctly.  I will DEFINITELY study dateadd and datediff just so I familiarise myself with it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As to "why", `DATEDIFF()` takes 3 arguments: `datepart` (string representation of a specific date part), `startdate`, `enddate` (both of which must be convertible to a date-ish object).

`0` is essentially SQL's epoch, which, in this case is `1/1/1900`. So the difference in months between 0 and `3/1/2019` is (119*12)+2 (+2 because we exclude March, since we aren't calculating a full month) = 1430 months difference.

Then, we are trying to add 2 months to our value. `DATEADD()` takes 3 arguments: `datepart`, `number`, `date`. But, in the example, you are adding 1430 months to whatever date -2 gets converted to (in this case, I believe it would be 12/30/1899, or 2 days before epoch). So, 1430 months after 12/30/1899 would be 2/30/2019, but February only has 28 days in 2019, so it returns 2/28/2019. In a Leap Year, it probably would return 2/29/2019.

To get your `@LastDayPrevMonth` and `@SecLastDayPrevMonth` with only `DATEDIFF()` and `DATEADD()`, you just need to change your calculations a little.

First thing you want to do is find the First Day of your Given Month. That can be done with `DATEADD(month,DATEDIFF(month,0,@CurrentDate),0)`. We're essentially using the same thing we used above to calculate the number of months since epoch, but then we are adding those months back to epoch.

Now that we know the First Day of the Given Month, all we have to do is subtract days to get a day from the prior month.

So,

```
DECLARE @CurrentDate date = '2019-03-15' ; -- Changed it to something in the middle of the month.

DECLARE @FirstDayOfGivenMonth = DATEADD(month,DATEDIFF(month,0,@CurrentDate),0) ; -- 3/1/2019

DECLARE @LastDayOfPrevMonth date = DATEADD(day,-1,@FirstDayOfThisMonth) ; -- 2/28/2019
DECLARE @SecLastDayOfPrevMonth date = DATEADD(day, -2, @FirstDayOfThisMonth) ; -- 2/27/2019

SELECT @LastDayOfPrevMonth AS LDPM, @SecLastDayOfPrevMonth AS SLDPM ;

DECLARE @FourDaysLeftInPrevMonth date = DATEADD(day, -4, @FirstDayOfThisMonth) ; -- 2/25/2019
SELECT @FourDaysLeftInPrevMonth AS FourDaysLeftPrev ;
```

Granted, since SQL 2012, this can all be accomplished much easier with the `EOM()` function to get to the last day of a month. But if you only could use the two original functions from your original question, this would be one way to get to your needed values.